# In RxJava, can zipped observable return to the main thread when it subscribed on the different thread?

Tags: rx-java

I tried below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Observable<String> zipped = Observable.zip(
    Observable.interval(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
    Observable.just("A", "B", "C"), (i, v) -> i + v);
  zipped.observeOn(
    Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

Since I used `interval`, `zipped` observable run on the different thread.
I want that `System.out::println` part run on the main thread.

I guess that I have to use `observeOn`,
but I have no idea which Scheduler I have to use for going back to the main thread.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get back to the main thread with `observeOn` unless you are on Android. For desktop use, you may use `toBlocking().subscribe()` to receive values on subscribing thread.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I knew that RxAndroid had the way to get the UI thread, so I wondered if there were the way to get the main thread. I thought that `toBlocking()` were for test or debug use only, so I did not come up about BlockingObservable at all. But there were no way, I might have to use it.